# xpath remove nodes based on child's attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, attributes

I have this xml code:

```
<osm>
  <count>
    <tag k="nodes" v="608"/>   
  </count>
  <node>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="5-10"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BA1 2BX"/>
  </node>
  <way>
    <tag k="amenity" v="nightclub"/>
    <tag k="facebook" v="https://www.facebook.com"/>
  </way>
  <node>
    <tag k="amenity" v="cafe"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BS3 2BX"/> 
  </node>
  <node>
    <tag k="amenity" v="school"/>
    <tag k="facebook" v="https://www.facebook.com"/>
  </node>
  <way>
    <tag k="amenity" v="church"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="BAX 5RT"/>   
  </way>
</osm>
```

I need to remove all nodes below `<osm>` which contain a `<tag>` node with the attribute `k` with the value `'addr:postcode'`:

```
<osm>
  <count>
    <tag k="nodes" v="608"/>   
  </count>
  <way>
    <tag k="amenity" v="nightclub"/>
    <tag k="facebook" v="https://www.facebook.com"/>
  </way>
  <node>
    <tag k="amenity" v="school"/>
    <tag k="facebook" v="https://www.facebook.com"/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

I've tried many permutations around this query, but it returns every occurrence of `<tag>`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="osm/*/tag[not(@k='addr:postcode')]">
```

I assume I need to find the parent, but that's where my knowledge runs out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right; you need to select the parent of `tag`. To do that, just select `*` and put the `tag` in the predicate.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="osm">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(tag/@k='addr:postcode')]"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working demo here: http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy23

Alternatively, you can add a matching template instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[tag/@k='addr:postcode']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce the same output. (http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy23/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is xpath to select all nodes under `osm` that doesn't include specific tag:

```
//osm/*[not(.//tag[@k='addr:postcode'])]
```

**Here is some important note for `not()` placement:**

> to search for element that doesn't include child element (any levels
>   below) use pattern:
>
> ```
> //element[not(.//child)]
> ```

please note that locator:

> ```
>     //element[.//child[not(@id=1)]]
> ```
>
> will select all elements that includes at least 1 child with id != 1.

So in example:

```
    <row class="row1">
    <cell id=1/>
    <cell id=2/>
    <cell id=3/>
    </row>
    <row class="row2">
    <cell id=1/>
    <cell id=2/>
    </row>
    <row class="row3">
    <cell id=1/>
    <cell id=2/>
    </row>
    <row class="row4">
    <cell id=3/>
    </row>
```

> ```
>      //row[not(.//cell[@id=3])]
> ```
>
> will select rows 2 and 3 (rows that doesn't include cell with id=3)
>
> ```
>     //row[.//cell[not(@id=3)]]
> ```
>
> will select rows 1, 2 and 3, but NOT 4 (rows that has at least one cell with id other than 3)

**So it's important where you place `not()` statement, as it could totally change XPath logic.**